# Using KCachegring with JRuby profiler

Tags: jruby, valgrind, profiler, kcachegrind

Is it possible to convert JRuby profiler graph output to valgrind format (or any other way to visualise profiling output in KCachegrind)?

Answer (score 0):

I think my new gem, 'jruby-profiler-callgrind-printer', should do the trick for you. It allows you to directly output callgrind formatted profiler data, which can then be opened up with Kcachegrind.

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/justfalter/jruby-profiler-callgrind-printer